# QT combobox's item border is see throgh QAbstractItemView's radius

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I would like to have a rounded rectangle shape of the popup by combobox, which is easy to implement as I add a "border-radius: 20px" to `QAbastractItemView`.( the 20px is just for easy identification for demo)

However, I also need to have a separator line between combobox items. I use item's `bottom-border` style to let items look like they have separator. But as you could see in the snapshot, there will be a extra bottom border appear behind `QAbastractItemView`.

How can I hide this extra bottom-border ? I search Qt's documentation, QSS has no `:last-child` or `nth-child` equivalent as in CSS. And there is no `sub-control` like `::separator`, so I cannot sytle the separator.

Could anyone has some clue ? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: How do you make your style, via css file or inside cpp code?

Comment: @bogdyname I use qss file. Would setting style via cpp code or css file make a difference?